# Kivy opens blank window when running even a simple program

Tags: python, kivy

I've just installed Kivy on a new computer, but I'm unable to make even the simplest of programs run as I can only make Kivy produce a blank screen with no content. There appears to be no problem loading the Kivy packages and no errors are produced when running the code below, and the program runs without issues on my other computer.

```
import kivy 
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Some text")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

I installed Kivy through Anaconda calling `conda install kivy -c conda-forge` in cmd as suggested by the kivy installation guide at https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html.

EDIT:
I ended up reinstalling Python and Kivy completely and this fixed the problem for me. I have no idea why, whoever.

Comment: when you run script in console/terminal/cmd.exe then it should display information. Maybe there is error message.

Comment: I get the whole "Kivy log" (not sure what to call it) describing what Kivy is doing. There's too many lines to include here, but I don't see any errors. The last couple of lines are:  

`[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [WindowSDL   ] exiting mainloop and closing.
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...`